# Pre-emptively mute notifications from tab in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, audio, catalina, notifications

I have messenger.com open in one tab. Sometimes I get messages and they play a ding.

How do I prevent these dings from ringing out?

I know it's possible to mute a tab that is playing audio by clicking the speaker icon in the tab title, but Messenger is not always playing audio.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This sounds like a [Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question because this is about the functionality of *their* website.  Your system has no way of anticipating which tab will play audio in the future.  There *must* be a setting on the site to mute notifications.

Comment: @Allan it's probably both :-) I would hope that Messenger has such a feature, but I can also see the benefit of being able to mute Safari tabs in advance, without muting all sound.

Comment: @nohillside, I can see a benefit, but currently, there’s no way. https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/mute-audio-in-tabs-ibrwae910b47/mac  Feature request?

Comment: I think this is totally answerable. It’s not a customer support in my eyes since it’s about how the software works and it’s not just, “I’m lost and don’t know where to start...”

Comment: @bmike - I would agree with you if it was *software*.  Since it's a web site, there's nothing really running on macOS other than Safari and it's the websites functionality that's in question.  Either way...

Comment: @Allan there is no way to mute a Safari tab when it's not playing audio?